# OpaLang: Limit not respected in query to MongoDB 2.6

Tags: mongodb, opa

Opa (https://github.com/MLstate/opalang) app made two years ago with MongoDB 2.2 survived migration of MongoDB to 2.4. Unfortunately DB queries are not working correctly anymore in MongoDB 2.6.

Version checked:

- 2.6.5 - officially supported by Opa since commit "[[version] bumped MongoDb to 2.6.5](https://github.com/MLstate/opalang/commit/047f58bfd4be35ee30176156b3718c707a6c0f76)",
- 2.6.6 - latest stable,
- 2.6-latest - nightly 5.01.2014,
- 2.8.0-rc4 - latest development.

Simplified working example:

```
type Article.t = {
  int id
}
database nadzieja_test {
  Article.t /article[{id}]
}
module Model {
  function get_articles() {
    /nadzieja_test/article[limit 2].{id}
    |> DbSet.iterator
    |> Iter.to_list
    |> List.mapi(function(i, item) {
      s = "get_articles()#{i}: id={item.id}" + "\n"
      jlog(s)
      s
    }, _)
  }
}
function page() {
  [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
  |> List.iter(
    function (id) {
      /nadzieja_test/article[{~id}] = {~id}
    }, _)
  <pre>{Model.get_articles()}</pre>
}
Server.start(Server.http, { title: "Test", ~page })
```

The query `[limit 2]` returns **all the documents**.

Real life problem was obviously more complex (both document stored and the query) but results in the same behavior. Original collection was using indexes, but dropping them did not remove the problem.

Database and collections was not existing before the test.
I stared with enabling profiling in mongo console with `db.setProfilingLevel(2)` (my app was tested with both profiling enabled and disabled). Profiling result obtained:

```
> db.system.profile.find({"op":"query","ns":"nadzieja_test.article"}).sort({ts:-1}).pretty()
{
    "op" : "query",
    "ns" : "nadzieja_test.article",
    "query" : {

    },
    "cursorid" : 152008290160,
    "ntoreturn" : 2,
    "ntoskip" : 0,
    "nscanned" : 2,
    "nscannedObjects" : 2,
    "keyUpdates" : 0,
    "numYield" : 0,
    "lockStats" : {
        "timeLockedMicros" : {
            "r" : NumberLong(278),
            "w" : NumberLong(0)
        },
        "timeAcquiringMicros" : {
            "r" : NumberLong(11),
            "w" : NumberLong(8)
        }
    },
    "nreturned" : 2,
    "responseLength" : 88,
    "millis" : 0,
    "execStats" : {
        "type" : "PROJECTION",
        "works" : 3,
        "yields" : 0,
        "unyields" : 0,
        "invalidates" : 0,
        "advanced" : 2,
        "needTime" : 0,
        "needFetch" : 0,
        "isEOF" : 0,
        "children" : [
            {
                "type" : "COLLSCAN",
                "works" : 3,
                "yields" : 0,
                "unyields" : 0,
                "invalidates" : 0,
                "advanced" : 2,
                "needTime" : 1,
                "needFetch" : 0,
                "isEOF" : 0,
                "docsTested" : 2,
                "children" : [ ]
            }
        ]
    },
    "ts" : ISODate("2015-01-06T11:05:26.170Z"),
    "client" : "127.0.0.1",
    "allUsers" : [ ],
    "user" : ""
}
```

Notice both `ntoreturn` and `nreturned` have value `2`. I am not sure is this Opa or Mongo problem. Any workarounds other then fetching from DB all the documents and filtering client-side (to many documents) are welcome!

Comment: Are you saying that the query you show in the profile output somehow returns more than two docs?

Comment: Yes, it returns all the documents, like there were no `limit` keyword.

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem in the MongoDB shell? Before your question I'd never even heard of Opa.

Comment: When I copy the `$query` from the `db.system.profile` into `db.MY_COLL.find(HERE_IS_MY_QUERY).limit(2)` it works correctly with two documents in result set. I do not know how Opa binding implements applying the limit, but it does the job in MongoDB 2.2 and 2.4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by MLstate guys with commit ["[fix] mongo: Ensure that the query limit is respected"](https://github.com/MLstate/opalang/commit/f80aecc75b3b0d80fa62aaa00e853c385a87dfda).